# Display notification message above HTML TD Cell permanently

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display notification message for each TD cell in HTML table permanently,
something like this,

[image]

How to get this please advise me

this displays notification inside td so td heights extending,

```
echo "<td title='This is Title' id=$colformfldid class=$k,1>";
                                                                echo '<div id="tool" style="background-color: lightblue;position:relative; "> '.$ques_res['message'];
                                                            echo $item_name;
                                                                echo "</div>";
                                                            echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried till now..

Comment: Absolute positioning. (Since anchoring that requires a parent/ancestor element with relative positioning, but that does not work for table-cell elements in Firefox, you should use an additional wrapper element.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood you correctly since your question wasn't that clear.

PHP

```
<?php
$name = "name";
$operatorname ="operator";
//(echo this in your table) echo "Hello, M. $name, my name is $operatorname,....";
?>
```

HTML

```
<table style="width:500px" border='1'>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo "Hello, M. $name, my name is $operatorname,...."; ?></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
</tr>
</table></body>
```

Comment: I want to display as popup message notification not as TD data

Comment: Like a javascript popup? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp It's hard to understand your question without some good information.